# Playing a video in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to play a video inside an HTML file and then inside a Joomla article (first want to try in a single HTML page).

I am using this code:

```
<video width="500" height="250" controls autoplay>
<source src="videos/video.wmv" type="video/ogg">
<source src="videos/video.wmv" type="video/mp4">
<object data="videos/video.wmv" width="500" height="250">
<embed width="500" height="250" src="videos/video.wmv">                                                               </object>
                                                                    </video>
```

I tried downloading a video from Youtube, and it works fine on Chrome and FF, but not on Opera.

However, the main issue - I have an avi (230MB) that I need to play. How could I do it? Convert it to an .wmv/.mp4? Or can I play it as an avi without external plug ins?

I tried renaming it from .avi to .wmv, tried online converters but it still doesn't work.

Could the problem be the size? The format?

Comment: Which online convertors did you try?

Answer (score 2):

> I usually have four versions of the same video for cross-browser
>   compatibly:
>
> ```
> <video width="320" height="240" controls>
>     <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
>     <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
>     <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
>     <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
>         <embed src="movie.flv" width="320" height="240">
>     </object> 
> </video>
> ```
>
> `.mp4`, `.webm`, `.ogv`, and a flash fallback `.flv`. This has worked
>   well for me cross-browser. Another thing to note is that for mobile, a
>   higher-optimised .mp4 video is more likely to work (I've had issues
>   with this in the past).

Source: [Making video tag play in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216212/making-video-tag-play-in-all-browsers)

Comment: That doesn't help, though.

Comment: If you explain in which way it doesn't help you, we might be able to help, instead of being unclear.

Comment: I mean in still doesn't play. The player is there, but the video does not play.

Comment: Sure you have converted them right? Opera should support webm and ogg

Answer (score 0):

did you tried `Video.js`? It's open-source and cool.

**In the `<head>`:**

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 60% }
</style>
```

**In the `<body>`:**

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
 preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"
 data-setup="{}">
 <source src="my_video.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
 <source src="my_video.webm" type='video/webm'>
</video>
```

[Here](http://www.videojs.com/) you could find more.

Comment: Tried it out - when using the .avi, it just shows the buffer icon and nothing more.